# FOSRestBundle returning empty content

Tags: php, symfony-3.4, serialization

I'm implementing FOSUserBundle in my project. I want a basic GET action to return a json object of the ContactList entity.

Controller:

```
class ContactListController extends FOSRestController
{
    use ViewContextTrait;
    const DEFAULT_GROUPS = ['organization_list'];
    /**
     * @ParamConverter("contactList", class="SchemaBundle:ContactList")
     * @param ContactList $contactList
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getAction(ContactList $contactList)
    {
        return $this->handleView($this->viewWithContext($contactList, Response::HTTP_OK));
    }
```

Trait:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Context\Context;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
trait ViewContextTrait
{
    public function viewWithContext($data, $statusCode = null, $groups = self::DEFAULT_GROUPS)
    {
        $context = new Context();
        $context->setGroups($groups);
        return View::create($data, $statusCode)->setContext($context);
    }
}
```

My `config.yml`:

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        include_format: false
    body_listener:
        array_normalizer: fos_rest.normalizer.camel_keys
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
```

**The problem:** When I call this route via postman (`/api/contact-list/1`), I always get a `{}` for my content in the Response object.

This is the dumped response:

[image]

**What am I missing in order to return the serialized ContactList entity w/ the context group in my Response?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
First of all, my annotations weren't included. I had to add this to my `config.yml`:

```
framework:
    serializer:
      enabled: true
      enable_annotations: true
```

Next, I forgot I had previously included JMS serializer into my project awhile back. Apparently the ViewHandler for the [Rest Bundle has a default order of serializer services](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/1-setting_up_the_bundle.html) that it uses. I ended up having to include this in my `config.yml`:

```
fos_rest:
    service:
        serializer: fos_rest.serializer.symfony
```

By default, FOSRest was using JMS Serializer which wasn't configured properly.